# Separating "user-owned" from "other" data in Django template

Tags: python, django

I have an Openstack-powered, Django-modified application that shows the disk images and snapshots available for a user to launch. The user currently sees both snapshots they created and ones they did not. I would like to separate the current table into two based on whether they are owned by the user or not.

My two table definitions are as follows (note I altered `row_actions` accordingly):

```
class UserSnapshotsTable(OldSnapshotsTable):
  cloud = tables.Column(get_cloud, verbose_name=_("Cloud"))

    class Meta:
      name = "usersnapshots"
      verbose_name = _("User Snapshots")
      table_actions = (DeleteSnapshot,)
      row_actions = (LaunchSnapshot, LaunchCluster, EditImage, DeleteSnapshot)
      pagination_param = "snapshot_marker"
      row_class = UpdateRow
      status_columns = ["status"]

class OtherSnapshotsTable(OldSnapshotsTable):
  cloud = tables.Column(get_cloud, verbose_name=_("Cloud"))

    class Meta:
      name = "othersnapshots"
      verbose_name = _("Other Snapshots")
      table_actions = (DeleteSnapshot,)
      row_actions = (LaunchSnapshot, LaunchCluster)
      pagination_param = "snapshot_marker"
      row_class = UpdateRow
      status_columns = ["status"]
```

I have altered the HTML template to pull the "UserSnapshotsTable" and "OtherSnapshotsTable" tables (I copied the original table and renamed both), but both full tables still generate under the respective headings. There are two functions generating the data:

```
def get_usersnapshots_data(self):
    req = self.request
    marker = req.GET.get(UserSnapshotsTable._meta.pagination_param, None)
    try:
        usersnaps, self._more_snapshots = api.snapshot_list_detailed(req,
                                                           marker=marker)
    except:
        usersnaps = []
        exceptions.handle(req, _("Unable to retrieve user-owned snapshots."))
    return usersnaps

def get_othersnapshots_data(self):
    req = self.request
    marker = req.GET.get(OtherSnapshotsTable._meta.pagination_param, None)
    try:
        othersnaps, self._more_snapshots = api.snapshot_list_detailed(req,
                                                            marker=marker)
    except:
        othersnaps = []
        exceptions.handle(req, _("Unable to retrieve non-user-owned snapshots."))
    return othersnaps
```

There are also Edit/Delete options defined for images, and imported for snapshots, that seem to have a key comparison. Here's the "Delete" one (line 7):

```
class DeleteImage(tables.DeleteAction):
    data_type_singular = _("Image")
    data_type_plural = _("Images")

    def allowed(self, request, image=None):
      if image:
        return image.owner == request.user.tenant_id
        # Return True to allow table-level bulk delete action to appear.
      return True

    def delete(self, request, obj_id):
      api.image_delete(request, obj_id)
```

How can I separate those tables out? This is my first time asking a question here, so please let me know if I can provide further information. Apologies for the length of it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you are using `glanceclient`. If that so you can use `extra_filters` parameter of `snapshot_list_detailed()` to filter only user images like this:

```
usersnaps, self._more_snapshots = api.snapshot_list_detailed(
    req,
    marker = marker,
    extra_filters = {"owner": "user_name"}
)
```

Under cover `snapshot_list_detailed` uses [GET images](http://api.openstack.org/api-ref-image.html) of Openstack Image Service API.

Comment: This worked for the User Snapshots section. I added `extra_filters = {"owner" : req.user.tenant_id}`. However, I would like to negate that for the Other Snapshots section. Tried doing `not req.user.tenant_id`, `!(req.user.tenant_id)` and `!req.user.tenant_id`. Can't find anything in the Horizon docs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, I'm afraid it is impossible with current API. You'll have to filter snapshots inside `get_othersnapshots_data()` yourself.